# Constantly passing data between two view controllers iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, rootview

I'm new in objective-c. I try to send data between 2 view controllers (for example controllerA and controllerB), but I need this data constantly, so I use _displaylink in controllerB to call method from controllerA.  I use player in controllerA and I want to display time etc. in controllerB. How to get existing instance of controllerA?

I try 2 different ways to do this, but both create new instance of viewcontroller

example 1:

```
 RootViewController *controller=(RootViewController *)self.presentedViewController;
```

example 2:

```
RootViewController *parent=self.parentViewController;
```

When I use this solutions I can call the method from controllerA (but this is method from new instance :( )

I also try this solution:

```
RootViewController *rootController =(RootViewController*)[[(AppDelegate*)
                                                               [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] window] rootViewController];
```

But when I try call the method in I get this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MMDrawerController
>   playerPositionS]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7c406c00'

Any ideas how to call this method correctly?

Comment: Both do NOT create new instance of viewcontroller. Is `ControllerB` a childViewController of ControllerA? Post some code to see the hirachie inbetween Controller A+B.

Comment: Use Protocol/Delegate

Comment: ControllerB is a modal called in ControllerA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In MVC as implemented in iOS/Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH14-SW1), view controllers refer to a *shared model*, not to to each other.  They should *observe changes in that model*, and then update their UIs accordingly.

A few ways to observe changes:

- [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) - connects changes to model values to a target and selector in the observer
- [Notification](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification) - allows the model to "post" that it's changed and view controllers to "observe" those posts.
- [Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) - this is the most direct (most overused, IMO) approach, where one object provides completes the function for another over some well-defined interface (a protocol).

Comment: I use both Delegation and Notification, because I need passing data in 2 ways. Thank You for help!

Answer (score 0):

As long as the view controller you want modified is in the navigation stack, I would try something like this to find the view controller whose properties you want to modify.

```
 let childVCs = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController?.childViewControllers
print("childvcs = \(childVCs)")

let myVC = childVCs[0]

let myOtherVC = childVCs[1]

myVC.someProperty = 100

myOtherVC.anotherProperty = 1000
```